# Error: Can't set headers after they are sent on page refresh

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

When I try to refresh a particular page, I get Error: Can't set headers after they are sent. Now, when I actually click a link to that page, it doesn't happen. I've looked through the chain of events during a request thoroughly. The middleware and request doesn't seem to be causing res.end() to be called twice.

Middleware being called on every request:

```
projectRouter.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var token = req.body.token || req.params.token || req.headers['x-access-token'];

  console.log(token);

  if (token) {
    jwt.verify(token, superSecret, function(err, decoded) {
      if (err) {
        res.status(403).send({
          success: false,
          message: 'Failed to authenticate token.'
        });
      } else {
        req.decoded = decoded;

        next();
      }
    });
  } else {
    res.status(403).send({
      success: false,
      message: 'No token provided'
    });
    next();
  }
});
```

Request error is happening on:

```
projectRouter.route('/projects/:proj_id')

.get(function(req, res) {
  Project.findById(req.params.proj_id, function(err, project) {
    if (err) { res.send(err); return; }

    res.json(project);
  });
})
```

I am using angular on the front end and am using an interceptor to write a user token to x-access-token. So when this error happens, the middleware fails to get the token, causing a 403 on that page. I've been trying to figure this out for a couple of days and am at a loss. I imagine it something really dumb though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
} else {
  res.status(403).send({
    success: false,
    message: 'No token provided'
  });
  next();
}
```

Your `else` block is sending a response and also calling `next()`, which means that it will send an error and also try to run your route and send a response. Since both are trying to send a response, you'll get an error.

Comment: Ah, well that seems to have solved the error, but not the token issue. The token issue exposed that problem, which is good ha. Thanks for the response!